# Python Pandas - Starts with and replace

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that contains numbers and strings. I want to find the cell that starts with '0' and replace it with Unknown

```
column1
12 - abcsffj
40 - dhjsadjal
0 - dahdalk
70 - dkalskda
```

I tried using .loc and contains but it also changed the cells that had 70 and 40 values.

```
df.loc[df['column1'].str.contains('0'), 'column1'] = 'Unknown'
```

Expected output

```
column1
12 - abcsffj
40 - dhjsadjal
Unknown
70 - dkalskda
```

Comment: Pandas has [`str.startswith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html).

Comment: Ha ha. My brain dint work for a min to replace contains with startswith. Anyways, thank you. It worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `str.startswith` rather than `str.contains` because `contains` will return `True` regardless the position of `0` in the values, whereas `startswith` will return `True` only if the values start with `0`

```py
>>> df.loc[df['column1'].str.startswith('0'), 'column1'] = 'Unknown'

          column1
0    12 - abcsffj
1  40 - dhjsadjal
2         Unknown
3   70 - dkalskda
```